A roof genus of high dimensional lens space
Let  $p$  be   a  natural  number, and  for  $i\in \{0, 
..., p-1\}$,
denote  the irreducible rank  one  complex  representation  of  $\mathbb{Z}/p$.  by  $\rho_{i}$.
Let   $a=(a_{1},\ldots a_{d}) $ be a  sequence  of  natural  numbers  between  1  and p-1,  and  consider $ L^{2d-1}(a)$,  the   Lens  space defined  as  the  quotient  of  the  unitary  sphere  in  the rank $d$ complex representation $\rho_{a_{1}}\oplus \ldots \oplus \rho_{a_{d}}$.
Is  the  $\hat{A}$- genus
$$ \hat{A}(L^{2d-1}(a) )$$
documented  somewhere in the literature? in  particular,  is  there  a  closed  formula  in terms  of  the  $a_{i}$  for  each dimension $2d-1$?

Isn't the A-hat genus zero for manifolds whose dimension is not divisible by 4, more or less by definition?

As Oscar says, the $\hat{A}$-genus isn't defined in odd dimensions. But you can find the Pontrjagin classes by the same method as for projective spaces. see Ewing, John; Moolgavkar, Suresh; Smith, Larry; Stong, R. E. Stable parallelizability of lens spaces.
J. Pure Appl. Algebra10 (1977/78), no.2, 177–191.  At that point, you can work out the A-polynomial, which is perhaps what you mean.
